# SQLite SELECT with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sqlite, select, for-loop

i have problem with a "select" query.
In my case, i have a loop (**for** the first) that scan my Array and for the current value my query must give a result.
The code is this below:

```
for (var key in arrayPlace) {        
        place = arrayPlace[key].replace(/'/g, '&quot;'); 
        place=$.trim(place);
        //Id place
        sqls.executeSql("SELECT * FROM luogo_accomodation WHERE nome_luogo LIKE '"+place+"'",[], function(tx,result){
            //alert(sqls);
            if(result.rows.length==0){
                alert("Error.");
            }else{
                //alert("Found!");
                var len = result.rows.length, i;
                for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
                    idLuogo=result.rows.item(i).id_luogo;
                }


            }
        }, null);  
        //alert(idLuogo);

  }
```

If i print the value of a variables "key" or "place" in the **for** (the first) i will have as a result the current value of the scan of the Array, but if i print this variables ("key" or "place") inside **the query result** i will have only last value of my Array.

So if i print the value of  variable "idLuogo" after instruction "**excetueSql**", commented "*alert(idLuogo)*", i will have the last result of my Array executed in the query.

I can not understand what is the order of execution of the loop and the query.

Can you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry, it is very hard to understand you. Especially, I have no idea what you mean by "print ... inside the query result", and also when you say "the loop" which of the two loops in your code you're referring to. Could you edit your question to make it clear what exactly you are asking?

Comment: I edited my question, I hope I was a little clearer now. Excuse me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with asynchronous execution. To simplify your code to important bits:

```
for(var key...) {
  // A
  ...
  executeSQL(...., function(..., result) {
    // B
    ...
  }, ...);
  // C
}
```

This says:

> For each `key`, first do A. Then tell the database "do some SQL, and when it is done, let me know so I can do B". Then do C, and repeat.

So, lets say you have two keys, `foo` and `bar`. The execution is as follows:

- A gets executed for `foo`
- Database gets told to do SQL for `foo`, and to do B when it's done.
- C gets executed for `foo`
- Loop restarts
- A gets executed for `bar`
- Database gets told to do SQL for `bar`, and to do B when it's done.
- C gets executed for `bar`
- Loop finishes
- The thread control returns to the runtime, which is now free to execute other things (i.e. to start listening for SQL's requests to do B). If SQL is done before this time, it will have to wait.
- Some time later, `foo` SQL is done, and executes B for `foo`.
- Also some time later (could be even before `foo` SQL is done`),`bar`SQL is done, and executes B for`bar`.

Now, in your `B`, you first display `idLuogo`, then you set it to a new value. This means that when B for `foo` executes, it will print nothing (since `idLuogo` hasn't been set yet), but when B for `bar` executes, it will print the last value that has been set there (which is the one from B for `foo`).

If you print `key` in B, the `key` loop has already done, so you're getting the last value it had while the loop was executing.

Comment: ok now I understand how these "calls" work.
But if I wanted to read the data from my array, watching as the result of the query and then immediately do anything else with that value, how can I do?

Comment: You do it from inside the callback - in the B segment (or in a function called from there). The SQL result won't be available at any other point in code (or in time).

Comment: All right. In my case I should do another query inside B, I tried but it does not work.
How do I do this query?
I did something like this: http://pastebin.com/0inq1dUe

Comment: It should work. The issue is most likely the fact that your `idAccomodation` again has the *same problem* - its value is only there in that one line, so you have to use it there. Since `idAccomodation` is a global variable, it will keep getting overwritten just like `idLuogo` was. You need to ask yourself rather, "what do I want to do with this result?"